# Обращение к методам класса как к статическим

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста по след. вопросу.
Почему работает этот код?

```
class test {

    function ftest () {

        echo 'ftsssss11est';    
        echo 'ftsssss11est';    

    }

}


test::ftest();
```

Мануал говорит что так нельзя. По умолчанию класс и методы public. Может происходит какое неявное преобразование типов?

Comment: Потому что во время исполнения не натыкается на ключевое слово $this. Возможно, метод помечается как статический на этапе компиляции, когда оптимайзер видит, что там нет обращений к экземпляру. PHP всегда не отличался строгостью к пользователю.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за всем ответы.

Ссылка на **Оператор разрешения области видимости** подтверждает мои слова, что так нельзя (Оператор разрешения области видимости позволяет обращаться к статическим свойствам, константам и перегруженным свойствам или методам класса),
но вывело на правильный ответ.

Введен новый уровень обработки ошибок  E_STRICT - для поддержки стандарта кодирования и выключающий обратную совместимость, он по умолчанию выключен и E_ALL  его не включает. При его включении подобный код выдаст ошибку **Strict Standards: Non-static method test::ftest() should not be called statically in**.

*То есть как бы это ошибка, но так как в предыдущих версиях PHP такой код наверно прокатывал, то типа мы закроем глаза на эту ошибку.*

Answer (score 0):

Это статическое обращение к функции

```
test::ftest();
```

он обрашается без создании переменной функции.

[можете узнать тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)